# RavenDb custom ID assignment

Tags: ravendb

I have a requirement for uniqueness of a document in a RavenDb database. So I followed the recomendation in docs -

http://ravendb.net/faq/unique-constraints

I also use the following code to get count of entities

```
public int GetCount<T>()
    {
        RavenQueryStatistics stats;
        _session.Query<T>().Customize(x=> x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()).Statistics(out stats).Take(0).ToArray();
        return(stats.TotalResults);
        //IQueryable<T> queryable = from p in _session.Query<T>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
        //                          select p;
        //return queryable.Count();
    }
```

When I use my own ID like Docs/Doc_1 then the TotalResults in way higher than actual documents in the database. When I browse it in the studio the document lower than TotalResults but the collections show higher number corresponding to TotalResults.

Looking at the other fields in RavenQueryStatistics class I found SkippedResults the correct answer for count is always TotalResults - SkipperResults . I found the following link in the documents to explain SkipperResults but in my scenario it does not clarify.

http://ravendb.net/faq/skipped-results

I think I am missing some fundamental ravendb concept. Any body has had similar experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds strange, and shouldn't really happen.
Can you try creating a failing test for this and send that to the mailing list?

Comment: Just to let you know that I am on an older version i.e. ravendb-build-426. This could have been resolved in later version. I will create a failing test with latest version on post on mailing list.....